# Add / remove class jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. I want to click DIV A
2. Div A adds div B the class "test"
3. when i click on Div C it remove the class "test" from Div B.

How is that possible?

My solution don't works :(

```
$('.a').click(function() {
    $('.b').addClass('ands');
    $('.c').removeClass('ands');
});
```

Here is my fiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mbqK7/1/)

Comment: I suggest you read the basics of Javascript before learning how jQuery works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.a').click(function() {
    $('.b').addClass('test');
});

$('.c').click(function() {
    $('.b').removeClass('test');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind click for '.c' also.

```
$('.a').click(function () {
    $('.b').addClass('ands');
});

$('.c').click(function () {
    $('.b').removeClass('ands');
})
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/w5V86/